# Run .NET Core tests from ASP.NET Core application programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit

I have some Exception when I am trying to run .Net Core nunit tests from ASP.NET Core application programmatically.

I am using:

- .Net Core Version="2.1"
- NUnit.Engine Version="3.10.0"

My code looks like:

```
var assemblyPath = @"C:\path\to\test.dll"
ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
TestPackage package = new TestPackage(assemblyPath);
ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package)
XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(this, TestFilter.Empty);
```

test.dll - has only one project with tests and this project type ClassLibrary.

When I run this code I have following exception.

```
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException: 'An exception occurred in the driver 
while loading tests.' 
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'test.dll, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot 
find the file specified.
```

How can I run .net core tests programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

the error says that file was not found, check the path and debug it to see if the file was loaded at `new TestPackage(assemblyPath)` line

even you can try to load the assembly as follow

```
var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
```